# Including categories in search results

Tags: posts, categories, search

I am trying to include categories in search results. I've been searching for hours now with no solution.

By "including categories" I don't mean search in a certain category, I mean let's say I have a bicycle store and have many companies included in the site; a user searched for `BMX mountain cross` for example. It will return the category BMX first (by clicking you'll be sent to the category page) and the posts related to the search term like WordPress normally does.

Does anyone have any clues or could point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using this code in my search.php above the main loop:

```
$search_term = explode( ' ', get_search_query( false ) );   
global $wpdb;
$select = "
SELECT DISTINCT t.*, tt.* 
FROM wp_terms AS t 
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt 
ON t.term_id = tt.term_id 
WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('category')";      
$first = true;
foreach ( $search_term as $s ){
    if ( $first ){
        $select .= " AND (t.name LIKE '%s')";
        $string_replace[] = '%'.$wpdb->esc_like( $s ).'%';
        $first = false;
    }else{
        $select .= " OR (t.name LIKE '%s')";
        $string_replace[] = '%'. $wpdb->esc_like( $s ).'%';
    }
}
$select .= " ORDER BY t.name ASC";
$terms = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( $select, $string_replace ) );
if ( count($terms) > 0 ){
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo '<li><a href="'.esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ).'" title="'.esc_attr( $term->name ).'">' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

This code does an extra DB query, but search for categories not only associated to returned posts, but does an extra seach for each word in a search term and brings all found categories - even empty.

Comment: David thanks. this might do what i am looking for but i've decided to use `get_term_by` and go from there. i'll accept your answer

Answer (score 7):

Use `get_terms()`, then you don't need to use a custom query to the database.

```
$terms = get_terms( 'category', array(
    'name__like' => $s,
    'hide_empty' => true // Optional 
) );
if ( count($terms) > 0 ){
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $term->name ) . '">' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Based on [birgire](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/26350/birgire)'s answer on a similar question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/239680/50432

Answer (score 1):

I've created a custom search results page that matches the keyword (s) with categories, posts, cpt's...

Here's sthe code for the categories (it also shows a category ACF field for images:

```
<?php
    // post categories in results
    $terms = get_terms( 'post', array(
        'name__like' => $s,
        'hide_empty' => false // Optional 
    ) );
?>
<?php
// list post categories in results
if ( count($terms) > 0 ) {
    echo '<div class="sr-categories">';
    echo '<h3 class="search-title">Category results</h3>';
?>
<div class="posts-wrap posts-layout-default  row">
    <?php
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>

        <?php
            echo '<article class="sub-cat-row col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12">';
            echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $term->name ) . '">';

            $taximg_id = get_field('image', $term);
            $taxsize = "grid-image"; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
            $taximage = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $taximg_id, $taxsize );

            if($taximg_id) { ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $taximage[0]; ?>" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
            <?php } else { ?>
                <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/default-image-600x400.png" alt="" title="" />
            <?php }

            echo '<div class="sc-title text-center">' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '</div></a>';
            echo '</article>';

            //get_template_part('template-parts/loop/content','listevents');
            wp_reset_postdata();
        }

     ?>
</div>
<?php echo '</div>'; // eof sr-events
} else {
    echo 'No Event categories found';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously possible, if it works like this, I'm using *TwentyTwelve*, you have to edit `search.php`. You will find the loop there:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

So, the loop is taking the `post_format()`. So you have to edit `content.php`. Here you will find these:

```
<?php if ( is_search() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>
<div class="entry-summary">
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-summary -->
```

Just change that to:

```
<?php if ( is_search() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>
<div class="entry-summary">
<?php the_category(); ?><br/>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-summary -->
```

If everything goes right, than it will echo the Category associated the search result. But if everything goes right like we want. :)

Comment: that is not what i was looking for at all but thanks. you are simply displaying the category name or the link if for the category if i recall correct,  i am not trying to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the @PhilOwen answer, I added the following to the top of my theme's [search.php](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page) page:

```
// post categories in results
$terms = get_terms( 'taxonomy-goes-here', array(
  'name__like' => $s,
  'hide_empty' => false // Optional
) );

if ( count($terms) > 0 ) {
  foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo '<h2><a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $term->name ) . '">';
    echo esc_html( $term->name );
    echo '</a></h2>';
  }
}
```

I think it will often make sense to display the taxonomy term matches–if they exist–above the specific items, as they would be higher up in the hierarchy of data.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way and wanted to share
no need that use $wpdb
this code work for me:

```
$val = get_search_query();
$categories = get_terms( ['taxonomy' => 'product_cat'] );
    foreach($categories as $cat){
    if (stristr($cat->name , $val)){
        echo '<tr><td><a href="'.get_term_link( $cat ).'" >' .$cat->name.'</a></td></tr>';
        break;
}
```

this code search in product category and It does not need to be exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM: As of march 2022, wordpress doesn't search for category or tag.

SOLUTION/WORKAROUND: Use a plugin to allow searching for category or tag. I've tested it with the free version of the Relevanssi-Plugin. https://www.relevanssi.com/features/. Other Plugins may work, too.

DISCLAIMER: I am not affiliated with relevanssi or any other wp search plugin vendor.

Comment: wordpress never searched in category, tags (or any kind of taxonomy in general) names or description. This is what the question is about. "use a plugin" is an obvious answer that realy do not add much and not in the spirit of answers expected on this site.