# Custom Query to search through categories

Tags: categories, query, search, mysql

I'm trying to display categories as search result items on top of the `search.php` results. There doesn't seem to be a standard WordPress function or WP Query to search through categories, so I figured I'd write my own MySQL statement.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.*, tt.* 
FROM wp_terms AS t 
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id 
WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('category') AND (t.name LIKE 'hout') 
ORDER BY t.name ASC
```

In the above example, the search term is "hout". However this doesn't seem to return any results. Can you see anything wrong with my query?

Or do you know of another way I can include categories as search result items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) function that's a wrapper for `WP_Term_Query`.

There you can e.g. use the `name__like`, `description__like` or `search` parameters.

**Example:**

Here's what kind of `WHERE` query they generate:

```
'name__like'        => 'hout'  >>>  (t.name LIKE '%hout%') 

'description__like' => 'hout'  >>>  tt.description LIKE '%hout%'

'search'            => 'hout'  >>>  (t.name LIKE '%hout%') OR (t.slug LIKE '%hout%')
```