# How to search only by post title and category?

Tags: posts, categories, search

I'm currently working on my first theme (based on underscores) and just realized the search does not return any results if I input a category name, nor does it give accurate results when searching titles.

So, how do I make my theme search **only** ***"post titles"*** and ***"categories"***? Should something be added to the Functions.php?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Including categories in search results](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84549/including-categories-in-search-results)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write a custom WP_Query in search.php.

Also since you want to search in `post_title` + `categories`, you might have to run 2 separate queries and merge results of them into 1.

Something like:

```
$q1 = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    's' => get_search_query()
));
$q2 = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'tax_query' => array(
        //YOUR tax query here
    )
));
$merged = array_merge( $q1, $q2 );
```

And use `$merged` to show your results.

Also you can also use `WPDB` to achieve this using MySQL query.

Comment: You solution will not return posts based on post title searched and category selected. 

In you cases all posts matching a text or all the posts of a category will be return.. It's and OR condition between post title and post category

How And condition between post title and post category handled ?