# Wordpress search not able to find the category

Tags: search

I have 3 to 4 categories on my website. I am using WordPress search but when I am searching my category then I am getting

> Nothing Found

also, I tried to search the subcategory then also I am getting the same message.

Would you help me out with this issue?

search.php

```
 <section id="primary" class="content-area mainSearch">
    <main id="main" class="site-main">
      <div class="equalPadding">
        <div class="cp-seeWrapper">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : 
          get_search_form();//search form
          ?>
          <div class="resultCount"><?php
          global $wp_query;
          echo $wp_query->found_posts.' RESULTS';
            ?></div>
         <div class="row">
      <?php 

       while (have_posts()){the_post();?>
        //displaying result here

       <?php } ?>

      <?php 
    else :
      get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

    endif;
    ?>
          </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </main><!-- #main -->
  </section><!-- #primary -->
```

Comment: WordPress doesn’t search categories. This is the normal behaviour.

Comment: Is there any way? Because I have categories which are, tech, Accessories, feature, and home. I tried to search tech and I am getting Nothing found.

Comment: At least it should be dislay the related product to the category while searching

Comment: You could use the code from this answer:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84549/including-categories-in-search-results You can use get_terms function in general to fetch terms of a taxonomy in your case terms of category.
Then in the get_terms() function's arguments you can pass the 'name__like' which will fetch terms with name like the one you pass. To pass the search query on the argument you can use the the_search_query() function. Hope it will help you. Sorry I am answering from my mobile.

Comment: Where should I add that code?

Comment: You can add it in your search.php file where the search results appearing. I would run the get_terms function before the if have_posts() then you should include in your if statement if the array is not empty because the get_terms function returns an array and also avoid triggering the get template function which runs if there are no posts and in your case there might be no posts but there might be categories to display. Then you can loop through the array of the get_terms before or after the while loop.

Comment: Little bit confusion. I am using a while loop to display the record if found and where should I use foreach ( $terms as $term ) {?

Comment: Before or after the while loop you can use your foreach loop

Comment: There’s probably a way, which I’ll leave for someone to answer, but what I’m telling you is that out of the box WordPress is not supposed to be able to search categories. Search only searches for the words in the title and content of posts. That’s it. So when you say “should”, you’re incorrect. It should not.

Comment: May I know the reason why this answer is downvote?

Comment: @JacobPeattie, You mean, there is no other option? Search only searches for the words in the title and content of posts.

Comment: There would be ways with code. All I’m saying is that it’s not a standard feature of WordPress.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, OK :)